# How to find out what % sessions included a particular event in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to optimise a website by firing events on various interactions. I'd like to be able to see in Google Analytics what percentage of users/page views/sesssions triggered a particular event. i.e. to complete these sentences:

- ? % of page views included the "scrolled half way" event.
- ? % of sessions included the "clicked ajax tell me more button"
- ? % of visits included the "used the breadcrumb navigation"

I can't seem to achieve this. I can only select basic things as the metric, not %ages as I need. Is there a way to do this on the platform or would I need to do something with the API?

I'm aware that I can get snapshot %ages by creating a segment that includes a filter for a given event, but I was hoping for a chart over time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using custom report with "Sessions with event" metric
[image: sample custom report]

Comment: Thanks but I think *Sessions with Event* means sessions with *any* event; I need to know about a particular type (catgory/action) of event.

Comment: No, they are event wise, but still have a lot of flows so my answer will not qualify. Here is a great article on events tracking http://help.analyticsedge.com/googleanalytics/misunderstood-metrics-events/ . Hope it helps